# Using Pandas to Change Data in an entire Excel Workbook

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel workbook that is very large in size.  Here is what I would 
like to do using Python's pandas. I am running python 3.4.

1. Open the workbook in pandas.
2. Change values in one cell to something different - for example, 
   change the string in cell A2 that is currently named "Jane Doe" 
   to "Bob Smith"
3. Bear in mind that I would like to select the entire workbook, not just one sheet.  My goal is to make multiple mass changes.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
xls = pd.ExcelFile('Data.xlsx')
df = xls.parse('Data')
df1 = df.replace('Jane Doe', 'Bob Smith')
```

Edit from answer:

Ayhan, thank you kindly for your response.

When I try to load the data using your method I get the following error:

```
fs = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheetname=None)
```

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call   last)
     in ()
    ----> 1 df = pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx")

```
/home/minx/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py in read_excel(io, sheetname, header, skiprows, skip_footer, index_col, names, parse_cols, parse_dates, date_parser, na_values, thousands, convert_float, has_index_names, converters, engine, squeeze, **kwds)
    167     """
    168     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
--> 169         io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
    170 
    171     return io._parse_excel(

/home/minx/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py in __init__(self, io, **kwds)
    216                 self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=data)
    217             else:
--> 218                 self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)
    219         elif engine == 'xlrd' and isinstance(io, xlrd.Book):
    220             self.book = io

/home/minx/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py in open_workbook(filename, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, file_contents, encoding_override, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows)
    420                 formatting_info=formatting_info,
    421                 on_demand=on_demand,
--> 422                 ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
    423                 )
    424             return bk

/home/minx/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py in open_workbook_2007_xml(zf, component_names, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows)
    792         x12sheet = X12Sheet(sheet, logfile, verbosity)
    793         heading = "Sheet %r (sheetx=%d) from %r" % (sheet.name, sheetx, fname)
--> 794         x12sheet.process_stream(zflo, heading)
    795         del zflo
    796         comments_fname = 'xl/comments%d.xml' % (sheetx + 1)
/home/minx/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py in own_process_stream(self, stream, heading)
    532                 elem.clear() # destroy all child elements (cells)
    533             elif elem.tag == U_SSML12 + "dimension":
--> 534                 self.do_dimension(elem)
    535             elif elem.tag == U_SSML12 + "mergeCell":
    536                 self.do_merge_cell(elem)

/home/minx/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py in do_dimension(self, elem)
    566             # print >> self.logfile, "dimension: ref=%r" % ref
    567             last_cell_ref = ref.split(':')[-1] # example: "Z99"
--> 568             rowx, colx = cell_name_to_rowx_colx(last_cell_ref)
    569             self.sheet._dimnrows = rowx + 1
    570             self.sheet._dimncols = colx + 1

/home/minx/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.py in cell_name_to_rowx_colx(cell_name, letter_value)
     89             else: # start of row number; can't be '0'
     90                 colx = colx - 1
---> 91                 assert 0 <= colx < X12_MAX_COLS
     92                 break
     93     except KeyError:

AssertionError:
```

Comment: so what have you tried and why doesn't it work?

Comment: ok, why doesn't that work?

Comment: Umm, if I knew why it doesn't work then I wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: are the changes not being applied to the worksheet? are the changes inconsistent? we can't read your mind. we need details

Answer (score 2):

Read all sheets into a dictionary:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheetname=None)
```

Create a writer object and iterate over dictionary while replacing based on key-value pairs:

```
repl_dict = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd', 'e': 'f', 'g': 'h', 'i': 'j'}
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('filename.xlsx')
for sheetname, df in dfs.items():
    df = df.replace(repl_dict)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheetname, index=False)
writer.save()
```

You may need to adjust some parameters of both [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) and [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) like header, index, etc.

Comment: Thank you, but this code works for only one set of results.  I have hundreds of
cells that I would like to update.  

Would I write the code like this?

dfs = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheetname=None

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('filename.xlsx')
for sheetname, df in dfs.items():
    df = df.replace('a', 'b')
    df = df.replace('c', 'd')
    df = df.replace('e', 'f')
    df = df.replace('g', 'h')
    df = df.replace('i', 'j')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheetname, index=False)
writer.save()
                    
I tried this method but it does not seem to work.

Comment: I have updated the answer for that case. In theory, what you did should have also worked. Did it raise an error?

Comment: Thank you, but I would like the search feature to be more specific. Because the order of items I would like to replace is not in order. It is scattered.

Comment: More specific how? The dictionary does not assume any order.

Comment: I will test this and let you know how it works. Thank you kindly for your help.

Comment: I know how to load an excel file into pandas. 

The command you wrote causes an error:
    
dfs = pd.read_excel('Motorist.xlsx', sheetname=None)

Can you offer any alternative ways of loading the file?

Thank you

Comment: It works on the sample file I tried but seems like a [bug](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/issues/56) I don't know how to fix that, sorry.

Comment: I really appreciate your help Ayhan.  My sincere thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of `pandas` (`pd.__version__`), the second parameter to `pd.read_excel()` might be spelled differently to the accepted answer. For version 0.21+ it's `sheet_name`, for older versions it's `sheetname`.